# Where does the name of Equational Reasoning come from?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I know [equational reasoning](https://wiki.haskell.org/Equational_reasoning_examples#Equational_reasoning) is that pieces of code can be replaced by others in any context, but am really curious where does the name of "equational reasoning" come from? I have googled it but could not find any relevant answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually not really a name, just a description that has become standardised through repeated use. "Equational reasoning" is just reasoning that is "equational"; i.e it involves *equations*.

The idea involved is that this series of rewrites:

```
fmap even . fmap (+1)
fmap (even . (+1))
fmap (\x -> even (x +1))
fmap odd
```

Involves the same *kind* of thinking as this series of rewrites:

```
(x + 1)(x - 1)
x^2 + x - x - 1
x^2 - 1
```

In both cases you're using equations like `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)` or `(a + b)(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd` that you know hold in general, and using them to transform your terms to ones that are *provably* equivalent. The *equations* are the key, which are previously proven to hold (ideally by someone else ;) ).

Comment: I often hear the phrase "reason about" or reasoning“, e.g., 'reason about program'. What does that mean?

Comment: @MattElson It's meaning is similar to "thinking". "Reasoning about this code" means "thinking about this code", except that it implies a particular focus on wanting to understand how/why it works, or to figure out properties that the code has. I general "reasoning" implies more rigor or productivity than general "thinking". "Thinking about this code" is less specific, since it includes any thought process I have related to this code. If I say "My reasoning is that ..." I'm about to explain to you my thought process; how I arrived at some conclusion.

Comment: @MattElson Does that sort of give you a sense of it? If not, that's probably an excellent question for english.stackexchange.com. :)